# Hibernate object equality checking

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

As far as I understand(correct me if I am wrong) Hibernate uses object reference to check the object equality. When Hibernate identifies that there are more than one objects attached to same DB record, it throws following exception.

```
"a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"
```

My question is, does Hibernate use `equal()` method to check the object equality (The default equal method uses object reference)? If it is true, will overridden `equal()` method change the Hibernate behavior?

Note: My question is not about the [issues of implementing `equal()` or `hashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719877/object-equality-in-context-of-hibernate-webapp) methods in a Hibernate persisted object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate uses the entity (i.e. class) and configured id. Over-simplified, this would look somehow like this

```
o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass()) && o1.getId().equals(o2.getId())
```